# Отключение соединения с сервером Plotly

Tags: python, графика, статический-анализ, plotly

Прохожу тему по блогу [рассказувающему, о временных рядах](https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/using-python-and-auto-arima-to-forecast-seasonal-time-series-90877adff03c) и все время, когда нужно вывести график в plotly вылезает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Либо же, если добавить функцию `plot_mpl` в

`from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot, plot_mpl`
То графики вылетают в закладку браузера HTML-формата

Как вывести графики в ноутбук?

Comment: Требуется аккаунт - вы об этой ошибке? Здесь написано как настроить для оффлайн работы в ноутбуках, взгляните https://plot.ly/matplotlib/getting-started/

Comment: Да, отключиться от аккаунта удалось, не удается нормально распечатать график по данным от функции seasonal_decompose(), там сразу 4 графика

Comment: А вы хотите печатать только какой-то один?

Comment: Я хочу печатать все четыре, но чтобы они оставались интерактивными и полноразмерными, как и положено в plotly.

Comment: Можете поделиться вашим ноутбуком и данными, которые используете, чтобы я мог быстро у себя запустить?

Comment: https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/using-python-and-auto-arima-to-forecast-seasonal-time-series-90877adff03c Вот по этой ссылке все скачивал

Comment: Вроде бы получилось, взгляните на ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так ([ссылка на отрисованный ноутбук](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/stpnk/14697bb6a553937bfcd6fee237bd297c)):

```
import plotly.offline as py  # Импорт plotly для работы в оффлайн
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
py.init_notebook_mode()  # Для отображения графиков в ноутбуке 


data = pd.read_csv("Electric_Production.csv",index_col=0)

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data.columns = ['Energy Production']

result = seasonal_decompose(data, model='multiplicative')

fig = result.plot()  # Вызываем метод для отрисовки графика
fig.set_size_inches(12, 10)  # Меняем размер
py.iplot_mpl(fig)  # Выводим с помощью plotly
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! Решение масштабируется и на другие датасеты

Comment: Про другие датасеты это вопрос был?

Comment: Нет, это результаты поверки метода и на другие данные. Спасибо.

Comment: А, понял. Хорошо. Наверное, должно работать с любым `Figure` объектом `matplotlib`. Метод `plot_mpl()` сохраняет html и открывает во вкладке браузера, `iplot_mpl()` - рисует в ячейке.

Answer (score 0):

В комментарии код бы некорректно разместился, поэтому разместил его в качестве ответа - сравните его со своим.

Думаю, что все дело в `init_notebook_mode(connected=True)`, без него в ноутбук не выводится.

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace0 = go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[9, 8, 7])
trace1 = go.Scatter(x=[7, 8, 9], y=[4, 4, 4])

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace0, trace1])
iplot(fig, show_link=False)
```

Comment: `init_notebook_mode(connected=True)` у меня тоже был активирован, еще в первых строках подключения библиотек. 
Но дело еще в том, что нужна именно функция plot_mpl, которая перерисовывает вывод matplotlib, полученный в свою очередь из функции `seasonal_decompose()`

`from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
init_notebook_mode(connected = True)
result = seasonal_decompose(data, model='multiplicative')
fig = result.plot()
plot_mpl(fig, show_link=False)`

Comment: Если же попытаться вместо `plot_mpl` использовать `iplot`, то возникает ошибка другого рода `PlotlyError: The 'figure_or_data' positional argument must be 'dict'-like, 'list'-like, or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.Figure`

Comment: @StepanSokol Выложите код и данные полностью, у меня не получается воспроизвести ошибку.

Comment: https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/using-python-and-auto-arima-to-forecast-seasonal-time-series-90877adff03c

Вот по этой ссылке и код и данные и пояснения автора